# Google maps API - how to include marker (and info) for specific business address?

Tags: google-maps

All the methods and examples I can find about the Google maps api is based on a postcode, or coordinates to get the desired location - what if I want to place a marker for a specific business which has been added to google maps, so it shows tel number etc like an embeded map would? Even if I use exact coordinates for the address it doesn't recognise it. Sure I'm missing something really simple here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[The Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/), this does what your looking for. I couldn't tell you how to implement as of now because i am trying to put it inside of my Rails application but i will update my answer in the future when i do get it working though.